# In rails, how to conditionally load javascript files

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, zepto

Using Rails 3.1, I'd like to load zepto when serving a browser that zepto supports (Zepto supports Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera and any mobile WebKit-based browser) and jquery in all other cases.
The motivation of course, is to provide a complete experience from one hand and a minimal file size, particularly for mobile devices, on the other hand.
What's the best technique? Is this approach discouraged? (see [Rails 3 Conditional Inclusion of Javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944919/rails-3-conditional-inclusion-of-javascript-files) for similar question and discouragement).
cheers.

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725905/zepto-fallback-to-jquery

Comment: well, that's almost a dup but I think I'll take it as close enough. what this doesn't cover is non-webkit mobile browsers. But that'll do for now... thanks