# Rails 4 asset pipeline: config.assets.precompile & conditional javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, asset-pipeline

I'm using an script to detect internet explorer and display a message. It is not referenced in application.js and I don't want to have it there because it is for one specific page of a controller.

Following this article (§3) http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/02/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-3-configuration/, I added in my config/development.rb file the following:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['iealert.js']
```

Now in my application layout, at the bottom, I have (using haml)

```
/ [if IE]
      = javascript_include_tag "iealert"
```

The script is included in 2 places, at the bottom, but also in the header (with javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true), therefore all browsers get the alert since the header inclusion is automatic and not conditional.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<!--[if IE]><%= javascript_include_tag "excanvas.min" %><![endif]-->
```

[Rails 3 Conditional Inclusion of Javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944919/rails-3-conditional-inclusion-of-javascript-files)

Could be wrong though :)